# Can't load native library on other systems

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, spotify

I'm developing an application that makes use of [libjahspotify](https://github.com/nvdweem/libjahspotify). The program is running on my desktop (Windows 7), when attempting to run it on my laptop (Windows 8.1) or on my other Intel NUC (Windows 7) I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\temp\jahspotify.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1929)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1814)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1083)
    at jahspotify.JahSpotifyNativeLoader.<init>(JahSpotifyNativeLoader.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at jahspotify.impl.JahSpotifyImpl.<clinit>(JahSpotifyImpl.java:730)
    at jahspotify.services.JahSpotifyService.initialize(JahSpotifyService.java:56)
    at jahspotify.services.JahSpotifyService.getInstance(JahSpotifyService.java:26)
    at jahspotify.services.JahSpotifyService.initialize(JahSpotifyService.java:39)
    at net.functionseven.divicantus.spotify.Spotify.init(Spotify.java:29)
    at net.functionseven.divicantus.Divicantus.main(Divicantus.java:20)
```

The native-jar in libjahspotify is supposed to load the dlls automatically, but does not. At this point it seems that jahspotify.dll is not loading. If I manually copy jahspotify.dll to the folder the native-jar will delete it, as its supposed to.

I've recompiled libjahspotify several times and checked it multiple times that both java and the dlls are x86. I've also attempted to load it manually with System.load(), I get a similar error like below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\temp\jahspotify.dll
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1083)
    at net.functionseven.divicantus.Divicantus.main(Divicantus.java:24)
```

I'm at a loss to what is happening.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please provide some code (best would be a SSCCE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely cause is that second system is missing some dlls that jahspotify.dll requires. You can check which dlls are required with Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and try manually putting these alongside jahspotify.dll. Commonly missing DLLs are from c++ redistributable packages and such.

Comment: That was it. Installed the VS c++ redistributes. Thank you.